# Vimeo embedding fails to work wit Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

I've read a bunch of resources about embedding vimeo videos on websites and rails but I keep encountering a problem in that the video fails to upload and I'm unsure as to why. I think it has something to do with my implementation. Below is code from my show page:

```
<h1>Music Videos</h1>

<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/#{music_video.url_id}" width="100%"   
  height="500" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen 
  mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>  
</iframe>

<%= simple_form_for [@music_video, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Submit Commented" %>
<% end %>

<% @music_video.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

I believe there may be a problem with the iframe src url but i don't think that I'm seeing it. Essentially my rails app works in the way that all you need to do is to copy paste the video id and it will append itself to the iframe src url using string interpolation. It makes perfect sense to me but the video refuses to play. The website on vimeo http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding makes the embed instructions crystal clear, so I'm thinking that the string interpolation is wrong somehow. I could use a fresh pair of eyes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it the case then that the videos have actually uploaded properly, but you thought they hadn't because the embed was broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you replace `#{music_video.url_id}` with `<%=music_video.url_id%>`?